# Manipulating Transformation parameters with PyQGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, pyproj

Is it possible to add a layer with a local coordinate system, transformed on the fly by a custom transformation entry from this local CRS -towgs84 and furthermore to manipulate the -towgs84 Parameters?

I would like to Helmert-Transform a Polyline from a geodetic survey by parameters I calculate with python based on ground control points.

I am aware of GDALwarp (only works with rasters) and the Georeferencer Plugin, which unfortunately does not support 7-Parameter Helmert Transformation.